# Scroll inside tbody

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a table and i want no scroll in page, but I want to scroll only in the table body (which will be only on 70% of the window) so the header will always be visible. I tried like this, but doesn't work:

Html style is:

```
<html style="overflow: hidden">

</html>
```

and my table's style looks like this:

```
<table>
<th>
...
</th>
<tbody style="height: 50vh; overflow-y: scroll;

</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Can you please add a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g23p05mq/1/ Check it out. the tbody is still too big.

Comment: Check this, it will guide you : http://joshondesign.com/2015/05/23/csstable

Comment: Here is a fiddle with your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/9c8ese72/3/

Comment: @bucurvlad Remove the css for html that you have added.